# Application doesn't run on older android versions

Tags: android, api, gradle, compilation, sdk

I have two phones, one with Marshmallow (API 23) and another with JellyBean(API 16) and I cannot run my application on the second phone. This is my gradle file app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

allprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
        targetCompatibility = "1.7"
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.branco.sauce"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'

    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/parse/AbstractQueryController$1;
```

At first, I thought the problem could be solved by downloading the API16 on the SDK manager(before that I only had API23 installed) but it didn't work. 
I have a guess that my problem has something to do with these lines: `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'` and `buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"` because they refer to API23 design or something like that, anyone can help?

EDIT: I get this following error now that I have specified the files I want gradle to compile:

```
InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class Button
at com.example.branco.sauce.ListViewAdapter.getView(ListViewAdapter.java:88)
```

This is where the error occours:

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if(view == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
            // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
            holder.txtDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
            holder.txtPoster = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPoster);
            holder.txtPoints = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPoints);
            holder.flag = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.flag);
            holder.btnUpvote = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnUpvote);
            holder.btnDownvote = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnDownvote);
            holder.btnFollow = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnFollow);
            holder.btnInfo = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnInfo);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
```

To be more specific, this is the line: `view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);`
and this is listview_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:id="@+id/txtPoster"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="64px"
        android:layout_height="64px"
        android:layout_marginTop="10px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:id="@+id/btnFollow"
        android:background="@drawable/follow_64_border"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="64px"
        android:layout_height="64px"
        android:layout_marginTop="10px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:id="@+id/btnInfo"
        android:background="@drawable/info_64_border"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnFollow"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnFollow"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"/>
    />



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="64px"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnInfo"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnInfo"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtLabelPoints"
        android:id="@+id/txtPoints"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5px"

        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtPoints"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/txtPoints"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnInfo"
        android:id="@+id/txtLabelPoints"
        android:text="@string/EN_txt.labelPoints"

        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="650px"
        android:layout_marginTop="10px"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtPoster"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:padding="1dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="128px"
        android:layout_height="128px"
        android:layout_marginTop="10px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10px"
        android:id="@+id/btnUpvote"
        android:background="@drawable/upvote_128_border"
        android:layout_below="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="128px"
        android:layout_height="128px"
        android:layout_marginTop="10px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10px"
        android:id="@+id/btnDownvote"
        android:background="@drawable/downvote_128_border"
        android:layout_below="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnUpvote"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnUpvote"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10px"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/btnDownvote"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnDownvote"
        android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
        android:lines="4"
        android:ellipsize="end"

        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You are using dynamic versioning in your gradle dependencies. One opinion on why not to do it: http://blog.danlew.net/2015/09/09/dont-use-dynamic-versions-for-your-dependencies/ Since there is a problem with com.parse.AbstractQueryController$1 you should probably start by assigned a static version for each library and look at where the conflict is occurring.

Comment: Google itself recommends not to use dynamic versioning (like that + sign) in dependencies. Write proper version number then try. You can go back on previous versions of libraries if they are available in case the latest version do not suit your needs.

Comment: You're both right, but now I get the following error: `InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class Button` I edited the question and posted the whole error and the line where it occours. Thanks for now.